# How to make an automated tour using Hopscotch library?

Tags: web, hopscotch

Hopscotch work well for me in developing tour for my website. 
I am looking for a way to automatically execute the tour steps with some custom time delay, but didnt' found any API for the same.

Comment: What types of things have you tried?  This is a pretty generic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hopscotch API provides a nextStep() method which could be called in inside of JavaScript's setInterval() method. Something like this would show the next step every 3 seconds.

```
setInterval(function() { hopscotch.nextStep() }, 3000);
```

Here's a working example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehomme/ucxxabju/).